# AJAX/jQuery/PHP Serializing Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form with AJAX but it's not working. The function executes but the ajax returns an internal 500 error in the console...

Te problem seems to be in the PHP file that I'm calling. I'm not sure if I'm using the serialized data correctly because when I replaced the values for the SQL with ones, it executed and was fine - therefore it is probably a problem with empty values..

PROBLEM FIXED- EDITED CODE BELOW:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="addIndicator" class="smart-form">

<input type="text" name="numerator" placeholder="Numerator">
 <input type="text" name="denominator" placeholder="Denominator">                                               
<input hidden type="text" value="1" name="iid"/>
<input id="indicator_submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="Add Data" style="margin-top:-15px;padding:6px;">


</form>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#indicator_submit").click(function(e) { 

   $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addIndicatorData.php',
    data: $("#addIndicator").serialize(),
    success: function() {  

     alert('success');  

   }
    });

alert("function working");
 e.preventDefault();


});
```

PHP:

```
$iid = $_POST['iid'];
$num = $_POST['numerator']; //numerator val
$den = $_POST['denominator']; //denominator val
$perc = ($num / $den) * 100; //percentage calculated


$abc = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO indicator_data VALUES (:iid,'',:num,:den,:perc,NOW())");
$abc->bindParam(':iid', $iid);
$abc->bindParam(':num', $num);
$abc->bindParam(':den', $den);
$abc->bindParam(':perc', $perc);
$abc->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery [serialise](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method returns a standard URL-encoded string representation of your form. In PHP, you need to [parse the string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) into a PHP array, e.g.

```
<?php
parse_str($_POST['indicator'], $input);
```

Note, that you need to give your object a name:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addIndicatorData.php',
    data: {
        indicator: $("#addIndicator").serialize()
    }
});
```

Comment: will the array's objects be named with the names fromof my form?

Comment: You need to start sharing the errors you are getting and the data that is sent and received.

Comment: This error was just syntax - i did share previously that it's just a flat Internal 500 Error

Comment: What do i do after parse_str()?

Comment: I got it to work - i just put in the code for the serialize directly in the data section and used POST in the PHP and it was fine.